# How to play music files in raw folder continuously

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

Creating music player related application,In raw folder having 5 mp3 files.want to play continuously and individually ,

```
else if (theText == song3) {

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hiii);
    } else if (theText == song4) {

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hiiii);
    }
```

This is how i am playing individual songs but how to play 5 songs continuously.Help me.

Answer (score 0):

1.make an array of id if songs in raw folder.

```
  int arr[]={R.id.hiii,R.id.Hiiii,...........}
```

2.use this array in your code

```
  mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, arr[i]);
```

3.implement **setOnCompletionListener(Context);** to start another song after one is over and loop it